# NRE на переменных класса MVC controller'а

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть проект WebForms (legacy) + ASP.NET MVC + SimpleInjector

```
public abstract class CustomBaseController : Controller
{
    protected User user;
    protected IAppDbContext repo;
    public CustomBaseController(User user, IAppDbContext repo)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
// my controller
[MyCustomAuthorize]
public class MyCustomController : CustomBaseController
{
    public MyCustomController(User user, IAppDbContext repo) : base(user, repo)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostMethod()
    {
         try
         {    
            // Какое-то обращение к полю user
            // Получаю NullReferenceException 
            user.Name = "NewUserName";
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            // логирование
         }
    }
}
// user entity
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Email { get; protected set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    public string FirstName { get; protected set; }
    public string LastName { get; protected set; }

    // and other properties
}

// Инициализация DI
private static void InitializeContainer()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IUserSessionManagement, UserSessionManagement >(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<User>(() => container.GetInstance<UserSessionManagement>().UserSession, Lifestyle.Scoped);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}

// Wrapper for User 
public class UserSessionManagement : IUserSessionManagement
{
    public User UserSession { get; }
    public UserSessionManagement(IAppDbContext repo)
    {
        UserSession = (HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_AUTHENTICATED_USER] as User) ?? new User(Guid.Empty, null, null);
    }
}
```

- Авторизация на куках
- В качестве DI библиотеки используется SimpleInjector. Он не может зарезолвить зависимость, которая [была бы null.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600492/how-to-inject-null-for-unregistered-services)
- Первое что пришло в голову. Вдруг где-то в контроллере переписываю ссылку. Я поискал все места использования поля `user` и везде только запрашиваю, а пишут только 1 раз в конструкторе `CustomBaseController`.
- **К сожалению я не могу это воспроизвести в дебаге. Наличие проблемы известно из логов.**

1) Пробовал подождать пока сессия экспарируется.

2) Пробовал залогиниться. Открыть еще одну вкладку в браузере. Выйти из первой. Сделать запрос со второй (ничего).

3) Сымитировать долгий запрос через thread sleep (но это фигня по-моему)

NOTE: Спрашивал на англоязычном SO, но мой английский слаб и у меня не получилось с первого раза объяснить проблему, когда к ней еще был интерес.

**UPD:**

Текст ошибки получается таким, где UserID пустой, потому что там через null propagation сделано. Соответственно user был null.

> An exception occured. Error id: c90dfe71-c608-4412-9805-c1cb9bf92bc6. UserID:;

Полное содержание вызываемого метода.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMethod()
{
    try
    {
        var provider = repo.GetProviderInfo(user.Id);
        return Json(provider);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var internalErrorId = Guid.NewGuid();
        MSSQLLogger.Instance.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())
            .Error($"An exception occured. Error id: {internalErrorId}. UserID:{user?.Id};", ex);

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, $"Error id: {internalErrorId}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы вот это `UserSession = (HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_AUTHENTICATED_USER] as User) ?? new User(Guid.Empty, null, null);` поменяете на это `UserSession = new User(Guid.Empty, null, null);`, то проблема воспроизведется?

Comment: и неплохо бы показать текст исключения с трассировкой

Comment: @tym32167, проблему не получается воспроизвести ни на дев сервере, ни на тестовых серверах. Трассировки к сожалению тоже нет, а только лог что метод упал из-за NRE.

Comment: тогда с чего вы решили, что у вас `user` был `null`? Может, проблема в другом месте?

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил описание в конец.

Comment: что то я запутался. Тут идет первый Error `An exception occured. Error id: c90dfe71-c608-4412-9805-c1cb9bf92bc6. UserID:;`, тут первый User `An exception occured. UserID:{user?.Id}; Error id: {internalErrorId}.`, тут вы вызываете конструктор `new User(Guid.Empty, null, null)`, которого в классе `User` нет, и может ли это `repo.GetProviderInfo(user.Id);` вернуть `null`?

Comment: @tym32167, каюсь. В этом контроллере есть два метода с похожим текстом ошибки, я скопировал с ошибочного места (исправил в самом вопросе). Конструктор класса `User` я пропустил в угоду лаконичности. Просто в моей ошибке подразумевает что поле `user` = `null`, а вызов через ?? при регистрации через DI уже полагает, что оно гарантировано не `null`. `repo.GetProviderInfo(user.Id);` может вернуть `null`, но тогда бы в тексте ошибке я увидел Guid моего `user`.

Comment: а у класса `UserSessionManagement`  есть другие констуторы? Есть вероятность, что в этом классе поле `UserSession` останется не инициализированным или перезаписанным пустым значением?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, конструктор один.  Напоминаю что DI библиотека `SimpleInjector` не может зарезолвить зависимость, которая будет равна `null`. Я проводил эксперимент и получал исключение еще на этапе создания контроллера. Выглядит это все так будто контроллер создается в обход DI контейнера.  Может ли быть такое, что зависимости не были зарегистрированы в контейнере в результате внутренней ошибки? Хотя тогда это противоречит выше сказанному.

Comment: как минимум я вижу у вас 1 проблему в коде, вот здесь `container.Register<User>(() => container.GetInstance<UserSessionManagement>().UserSession, Lifestyle.Scoped);` вы резолвите класс `<UserSessionManagement>`, хотя регистрировали интерфейс `Register<IUserSessionManagement, UserSessionManagement >`, интерфкйс вы регали с `Lifestyle.Scoped`, а класс у вас каждый раз создается заново и не связан со скоупом, в этом может быть проблема. Я бы резолвил то, что регал - интерфейс.

Comment: но если в общем говорить, я бы вообще в контроллер прокинул не `User`, а `IUserSessionManagement`, и фабрики тогда не нужны

Comment: @tym32167 с интерфейсом верно подмечено. Сделаю как вы предложили. Но т.к. в внутри  `UserSessionManagement` все равно тянет данные из сессии, то `user`  там должен оставаться до конца завершения запроса. Все равно считаю что причина где-то в другом месте зарыта.

Comment: Не совсем так, `container.Register<User>(() => container.GetInstance<UserSessionManagement>().UserSession, Lifestyle.Scoped);` - почему у вас эта зависимость Scoped? Это ведь означает, что этот объект создается 1 раз на запрос, и после уже ссылка на юзера будет храниться в контейнере. Предлагаю вам вообще выпилить эту строчку, и резолвить в контроллере `IUserSessionManagement`, и от него уже получать юзера

Comment: @tym32167 так ведь при всех передачах будет передаваться именно ссылка, а не сам объект. Если затереть ссылку на объект в одном месте, то она должна остаться в другом,потому что контроллер уже создали. Ведь так?

Comment: да, ссылка, которая scoped в контейнере, это мне и не нравится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в следующем: так как все хранилось в сессии и после перезагрузки IIS (или обновления `web.config`) там ничего не лежит. 
В сессию информация о юзере попадает после того как происходит обращение к любой странице написанной на WebForm, то бишь отрабатывает логика `Admin.Master`, но т.к. присутствует лапша из разных технологий, то при прямом обращении через ajax запрос логика из `Admin.Master` не отрабатывала. Проще говоря забыли добавить это в кастомные атрибуты авторизации.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, что бы я посоветовал:

```
// Инициализация DI
private static void InitializeContainer()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IUserSessionManagement, UserSessionManagement>(Lifestyle.Scoped);    
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

Базовый класс

```
public abstract class CustomBaseController : Controller
{
    protected IUserSessionManagement SessionManagement;
    protected IAppDbContext repo;
    public CustomBaseController(IUserSessionManagement sessionManagement, IAppDbContext repo)
    {
        this.SessionManagement = sessionManagement;
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

Котроллер

```
// my controller
[MyCustomAuthorize]
public class MyCustomController : CustomBaseController
{
    public MyCustomController(IUserSessionManagement sessionManagement, IAppDbContext repo) : base(sessionManagement, repo)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = SessionManagement.UserSession;
            // Какое-то обращение к полю user
            // Получаю NullReferenceException 
            user.Name = "NewUserName";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // логирование
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все оказалось проще. Банальная невнимательность:)
Спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: @adrug пожалуйста, рад, что всё разрешилось